# My microphone has an extra channel full of random noise, how do I disable the extra channel?

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, microphone, google-hangouts

EDIT: I still have this problem as of 6/20/2016
My microphone works just fine in Windows 10. When I try to use Google Hangouts in Ubuntu I am almost completely inaudible over the random noise from my mic.
Google Hangouts automatically changes my microphone settings, so muting the broken channel only fixes things for a few seconds. I want to disable the broken channel so that Google Hangouts can't use it.

This is a recording of me making snap noises. The bottom channel is the broken channel which is full of maximum volume random noise. The top channel sounds like the mic does in Windows 10.
[image: audacity]

I am on a Gigabyte P25X V2 using the built-in microphone.

uname -a:

```
Linux Hyperion-K 3.16.0-60-generic #80~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 20 13:37:48 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

cat /etc/issue

```
Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS \n \l
```

some of lspci output:

```
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
```

according to alsamixer:

```
Card: HDA Intel PCH
Chip: Realtek ALC282
```

Answer (score 3):

Install **PulseAudio Volume Control** from Ubuntu Software Center. Then go to "Input Devices" tab and silence one of the channels. You can also choose settings per application, start Google Hangouts and go to "Recording" tab where you will find your application, and here you can also change recording settings for specific application. Third way is to choose suitable profile in "Configuration" tab.

I haven't experienced your specific problem, but **PulseAudio Volume Control** is very good application with a lot of options, it helped me solving various other issues many times, so I am almost sure it will help you with this case as well.

Comment: An alternative way to install would be via terminal: `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`

Comment: Whenever I say something loudly enough Google Hangouts sets both left and right (right is the noisy channel) to a bit higher than the left channel was. So if I'm talking to somebody I have to keep fighting it and the person I'm calling has to endure a lot of loud noises every time it comes back on. I've already been using pavucontrol for a while now, I've done plenty of research and asked here as a last resort.

Comment: Hm, since Google Hangouts overrides your choice... The question now is, why that channel is noisy in the first place. My mic, for example, is also recording stereo, but both channels are the same without any noises.  Maybe you could choose another  profile in "Configuration" tab, but likely you have tried this already. So you need to fix that channel (make noises dissapear) in some other way, hm.